# How to nest .or() and .and() conditions in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a 'search' function where I want to pass in an arbitrary 'filter' condition and have matches returned

The following matches any name/email where the filter string is a match:

```
@people = Person.all
@people = @people.or(
    {'name.first_name' => /#{filter}/i}, 
    {'name.last_name' => /#{filter}/i}, 
    {'email' => /#{filter}/i }
)
```

The following correctly does the same on the 'tags' array on the Person record:

```
@people = Person.all
@people = @people.any_in('tags' => [/#{filter}/i])
```

Can anyone tell me how to combine the two queries, so that a Person is matched if the filter text is found in the name, email or any of the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a method I was missing here ... found indirectly via https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2845

Given these two queryables:

```
a=Person.where({'name.first_name'=> /a/i})
b=Person.where({'name.first_name'=> /j/i})
```

You can combine them using .selector

```
Person.or(a.selector, b.selector).to_a
=> selector={"$or"=>[{"name.first_name"=>/a/i}, {"name.first_name"=>/j/i}]}
```

or

```
Person.and(a.selector, b.selector).to_a
=> selector={"$and"=>[{"name.first_name"=>/a/i}, {"name.first_name"=>/j/i}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `any_in` at all. If say:

```
:array_field => regex
```

then MongoDB will automatically check each element of `array_field` against `regex` for you, you don't have care about the arrayness at all. That means that you can toss the `:tags` check in with the other conditions:

```
regex   = /#{filter}/i
@people = Person.where(
    :$or => [
        { 'name.first_name' => regex },
        { 'name.last_name'  => regex },
        { 'email'           => regex },
        { 'tags'            => regex }
    ]
)
```

I also pull the regex out of the query into a variable to make it clear that you're using the same one for each check and I switched to `where` as that's more common (at least in my experience).

Comment: Cheers - this will allow me to do it construction the hash with the conditions, my problem will also come back though when it is to do with scopes ... how can you combine the Mongoid DSL methods/queryable's this way? (ie the way you would pass around AR queryables to compose them)

Comment: All the scopes will be available on the Mongoid::Criteria that `where` hands you and vice versa: `Person.where(...).some_scope` or `Person.some_scope.where(...)`.

Comment: But again, this doesn't combine the queries, only refines (ie it is an 'and') I can't find how to do an 'or' of Mongoid criteria

Comment: Actually it doesn't 'and' - it appears to replace:  Person.where({'name.first_name'=> /a/i}).where('name.first_name'=> /b/i).to_a  results in selector={"name.first_name"=>/b/i}

Comment: Internally it is doing little more than building a Hash and `M.or(array)` is just a different way of saying `:$or => array`. But if you `M.or(array1).or(array2)` you build `:$or => array1 + array2`. Is that what you're looking for?